# Sort list of current time and date objects in python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, datetime

The following code snippet prints the current date and time object.

```
from dateutil.tz import *
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
local = tzlocal()
now = datetime.now()
now = now.replace(tzinfo = local)


tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
your_now = now.astimezone(tz)
print (your_now) # 2020-02-19 00:29:00.296364+05:30
```

As mentioned above current time is printed as "**2020-02-19 00:29:00.296364+05:30**"

If I have a list of such date time objects, does **sorted(list_name)** will sort all the current time and date objects?

Comment: It should (produce a sorted version without changing the original - use `list_name.sort()` to sort in-place). Have you tried it?